# How to encrypt reset password URL in ASPX?

Tags: asp.net, encryption

I am not asking how to program the feature, I am asking how to encrypt the URL for the password reset, and to make it temporary under aspx. What is the best encryption method for that, md5, base64 or what ??

For example:
mysite.com/account/resetpass.aspx?sg=2c9P8uK6VJlJ&mp=2c9VPKR4LnwEI

Thanks

Comment: I think a better approach is to send the password in the POST data over SSL. URLs tend to be cached by the user's browser and web server logs.

Comment: @FrankFajardo OK, suppose that I did it as a POST request, is it possbile to be decrypted ?

Comment: Yes, if the request is intercepted and the attacker knows how to encrypt the request (ie, your encryption is weak).

Comment: On the other hand, if you put the password in the URL, it will also appear on the browser history, and most likely in the logs of the server that can decrypt the request.

Comment: @FrankFajardo Noted, thanks for sharing. But if I want to test the strength of my encryption and want to decrypt it, how to do that ?

Comment: I'm not an expert on cryptography. I would not recommend a novice in the area doing it for a production system. But you could certainly read about various encryption algorithms. [Cryptograhic algorithms and protocols](http://www.dwheeler.com/secure-programs/Secure-Programs-HOWTO/crypto.html) change as computing power used to overcome them improve. So implementing them is not for the faint-hearted.

Comment: Since you're doing password resets, try reading Troy Hunt's blog on [Password Reset Features](https://www.troyhunt.com/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know/) and [Lousy Cryptography](https://www.troyhunt.com/lousy-abc-cryptography-cracked-in/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, what a great website and people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
     protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encrypt(userName.Trim()));
        string technology = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encrypt(password.Trim()));
        Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/page.aspx?sg={0}&mp={1}", name, technology));
    }  



 private string Encrypt(string MyText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(MyText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                MyText= Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return MyText;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Div , what is the encryption type above ?

Comment: @Kimo, This is  Advanced Encryption Standard(AES) technique.

Comment: You're welcome! @Kimo, Is it exactly that you asked for?

Comment: Yes it is, I am studying Information Security, and trying to build a secured applications. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad that you got an answer. Accept this as your answer, so others can use this when they will have same issue.